# Why do i get the original again as a result after i get the list with the desired number removed?

Tags: list, prolog

i was trying to implement a prolog rule which removes the number X from a certain list and returns the list without the X . However after getting the correct result i get as an alternative the original list as a result as well and i get figure out where is the problem in my code.

```
remove1(X,[],[]).
remove1(X,[X|T],T).
remove1(X,[H|T],[H|R]):-
    X \= H,
    remove1(X,T,R).
remove1(X,[H|T],[H|T]):-
    \+member(X,T).
```

Comment: Because Prolog backtracks and takes the last branch. Why do you use the last branch anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Let's answer that with an example. Say we remove `2`, from `[1,2,3]`. Then Prolog will evaluate it like this:

```
remove1(2,[1,2,3],R):
    fail. % clause 1
    fail. % clause 2
    2 \= 1, remove1(2,[2,3],R'): % clause 3
        fail. % clause 1
        R = [1,3] % clause 2
        2 \= 2... fail. % clause 3
        \+member(2,[3]),R=[1,2,3] % clause 4
    \+member(2,[2,3])... fail. % clause 4
```

(answers put in boldface)

So once Prolog has found the first answer, it backtracks, checks if `2` is a member of the tail `T=[3]` (which it is not), and thus replies (based on the last clause) that `[1,2,3]` is an answer as well.

It makes me wondering why you added the last clauses. If `2` cannot be found, Prolog would have answered the list anyway. So the program:

```
remove1(X,[],[]).
remove1(X,[X|T],T).
remove1(X,[H|T],[H|R]):-
    X \= H,
    remove1(X,T,R).
```

Would be sufficient.

If you however want the query to succeed **only if it has deleted one occurrence**, you should remove the first query as well. So:

```
remove1_force(X,[X|T],T).
remove1_force(X,[H|T],[H|R]):-
    X \= H,
    remove1(X,T,R).
```

Both predicates will only remove the *first* occurrence of `X` in the list. So `remove1_force(1,[1,2,3,1,2,3],R)`. Will only give one answer: `R = [2,3,1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the first and the last clause are unnecessary. The last clause is where the wrong results come from.

This seems to be another "textbook" predicate, and it is usually called `select/3`. The textbook definition in [Sterling&Shapiro], page 67, is identical to the [SWI-Prolog library implementation](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#select/3) and goes something like this:

```
%!  select(?Elem, ?List1, ?List2)
%
%   Is true when List1, with Elem removed, results in List2.

select(X, [X|Tail], Tail).
select(Elem, [Head|Tail], [Head|Rest]) :-
    select(Elem, Tail, Rest).
```

You will notice that it does not need any helper predicates and is a true relation. Try for example:

```
?- select(X, [1,2,3], R).
```

or even:

```
?- select(X, List, Rest), numbervars(List).
```

(`numbervars/1` just makes the solutions a bit more readable)

This definition is as general as it is because... well, it is a general definition. The first clause does the "selecting", the second clause defines the recursive step.

[Sterling&Shapiro]: Sterling L, Shapiro EY. The art of Prolog: advanced programming techniques. MIT press; 1994.